# Python calling function from other file

Tags: python

I have two python files
First python code in file 1:

```
import simpleT

def funcion():
   print "Function called"
if __name__=="__main__":
  try:
     simpleT.Door().start()
     while True:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print "Main Op"
```

File 2(simpleT.py)

```
import threading
import time
class Door(threading.Thread):   
  def __init__ (self):
     threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  def run(self):    
     funcion()
```

Step 1:
I can execute the function if the class of thread is in the same file
Step 2:
I want split it, execute "function" localted on file 1 that containts the main function from the thread located on file 2 but error say:
NameError: global name "function" is not defined
how can i call this function?..is there super class or parameter required?

Comment: You have to import it, but to prevent circular imports you should put `function` into `simpleT.py` instead. This is BTW unrelated to threading.

Comment: So..basically i can't call from thread..i need to put into simpleT.py..is that right?

Comment: Is there anything my earlier comment left unclear?

Comment: As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you had provided a [mcve], you would also have found out that this problem is not related to threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `function` from file 1 in simpleT.py But in that way, it will be a cyclic import and will throw an error.

So the best would be to create a new module for `function`

`file2.py`

```
def funcion():
    print "Function called"
```

Then import this function in `simpleT.py`

```
import threading
import time

from file2 import function


class Door(threading.Thread):   
    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):    
        funcion()
```

and then in `file1.py`

```
import simpleT


if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        simpleT.Door().start()
        while True:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print "Main Op"
```